# how to create a customized drilldown report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I currently have this awesome drill down::

[image]

what i would like to do is this:::

[image]

another words, instead of having a separate field (per se), i would like the section of text all the way on the right to be embedded together with the stuff all the way on the left.

i would like it to also be expandable.

is this possible?

**if not, what is a workout around, or at least a solution that is similar?**

it might be helpful to show you the report in design mode:

[image]

Comment: you can use a rectangle in the 'cell' and then place the name and comment in it

Comment: thank you very much for the response. can you show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: @TI or a link to such a solutionwould be most appreciated! thank you so much

Comment: please let me know if anything needs clarifying

Comment: @TI would be very grateful if you could elaborate on your commnet

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239330.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe merging will work for you in the detail  but this would be ideal. However as a workaround and forgive me as I haven't got report builder with me but if you follow a few steps:

1. Expand the row for clarity and drop a tablix into it.
2. Be sure to set the correct filters in the sub tablix.
3. Add a group that has the name as the main and the comments as the detail.
4. Have the name be the toggle for the detail.
5. And for visuals be sure to remove all borders and create the background the same colour.

Sorry if the detail is a little off, I can't test this out, but I hope I get you going.